# PDFMiner extract text from PDF without mixing the order

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I have the following text in a PDF:

```
STUDENT ________JOHN______
DATE ______MM/DD/AAA______ (date)
COURSE ___________________ PROFESSOR ___________
```

When I use PDFMiner to extract the text, I get the following:

```
STUDENT ____
DATE MM/DD/AAA
(date)
JOHN
COURSE 
___________________ 
PROFESSOR 
___________
```

How can I get the correct output using PDFMiner (or other Python lib)?

Comment: My understanding is that PDFMiner uses [pdf2txt](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt) to extract text and I'm guessing that it is just extracting text in the order that it was added to the PDF. Trying padding the `-t xml` option which will give you a more detailed document and you should be able to write whatever logic you want to then.

Comment: Do you get better results when you make accessible the PDF before using PDFMiner?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am running into the same problem.

Comment: @Yeagz, not really, but I was able to run through the tree and find data with an specific name, get it's bbox and find all data within the same like (with a given margin which may differ from line to line). I was able to "solve" my problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do to that is by extracting the PDF as HTML using pdfminer HTMLConverter.
A typical command will be:

pdf2txt.py -t html -o outputFilePath/outputFileName.txt YourPDFpath/PDFname.pdf

Further processing can get you in some encoding dilemma, so better define the encoding as either utf-8 or cp1252.Example:

pdf2txt.py -t html -c cp1252 -o outputFilePath/outputFileName.txt YourPDFpath/PDFname.pdf